# Translating texts, that appear only in one language

Tags: php, yii, localization, translation

I have a dual-language (English and Polish) application written in Yii 1.x. Base langauge is English (`sourceLangage`) and current language (`language`) is controlled by user.

How should I translate, using `Yii::t`, strings, that are not used in English, but should be visible in Polish? I can't call `Yii:t('app', '');`, right?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example? If strings aren't used in English, then they're not a translation, but conditionally added content. As such, don't use `Yii::t`, just `if`.

Comment: @deceze You mean, checking `Yii::app()->language` in each such point? That sounds like a bit craziness. An example are dates. In English we write just `6 October 2014`, while in Polish we add `r.` at the end (an abbreviation of Polish `rok` = `year`), so: `6 października 2014 r.`. I could use just bare PHP's `date()` for this purpose, only... [it seems to be not working for me in Yii](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29078644/1469208).

Comment: Specifically for a date format, you should localise the date format string, like `d F Y` → `d F Y \r.`, `date(Yii:t('d F Y'))` (completely glancing over the problem you have with this at the moment). Then it's not "a string that isn't used in English", it's just a different date format. For "strings that aren't used in English" I was thinking about something like specific legal disclaimer sections which are only used in one language or another.

Comment: @deceze What you propose, sounds like a good solution. Consider writing an answer out of this comment, so I can accept it and bring you some rep (if you care).

Comment: @deceze Another question, if `date(Yii:t('d F Y'))` supports locales?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would classify "strings not used in English" as something like entire paragraphs which are only relevant in one language or another; for example you may need an additional explanatory paragraph for a concept which is "foreign" in one culture but natural in another, or you may be required to display certain legal phrasing in one country but not another. In these cases, it's not really a "translation", but conditional content. As such, an `if` statement based on the current language is the natural way to go, or similar equivalents (e.g. `include "legal.$lang.html"`).

The specific example you mention in the comments, of a different *date format*, is just a classical case of localisation, for which the regular translation functions will do just fine:

```
echo date(Yii:t('d F Y'));
```

This date formatting string `d F Y` may need to be localised to `d F Y \r.` in Polish. Note that `date` is *not* able to localise dates. If at all possible, you should be using the [`IntlDateFormatter`](http://php.net/IntlDateFormatter) class, and typically you'd use constants for different "kinds" of date formats, like `IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM` (Jan 12, 1952), `IntlDateFormatter::SHORT` (12/13/52) etc. Otherwise, [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) hooks into the locale system and is able to format dates locale based. I don't know how either tie into Yii specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use like `Yii:t('app', '');` because as source code you have to provide with some unique symbols (key words). You can try something like this define all undefined translate like

`['undefined_1' => 'Correct translation',  'undefined_2 => 'Another correct translation', ... , 'undefined_n' => 'More other translation'];`

And use code like

`<?= preg_match("/undefined_/", Yii:t('app', 'undefined_n')) ? Yii:t('app', 'undefined_n') : '' ?>`

Maybe it's not best solution but it's as a version.